# Not able to send text in Coded UI

Tags: c#, text, coded-ui-tests

Here this is my code I try to send text to the text box but I can't  it is not working.

```
ITestControl PointBuildWin = new UITestControl();
PointBuildWin.TechnologyName = "MSAA";
PointBuildWin.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.378734a";
PointBuildWin.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.FriendlyName] = "XLS80ePSPointUtility";    

Thread.Sleep(3000);
WinRadioButton UpgradePointBuildBtn = new WinRadioButton(PointBuildWin);

UpgradePointBuildBtn.SearchProperties[WinRadioButton.PropertyNames.Name] = "Upgrade from earlier version of EBI and XLS80ePS";

Mouse.Click(UpgradePointBuildBtn);

Thread.Sleep(1000);

WinCheckBox PointSpecButton = new WinCheckBox(PointBuildWin);
PointSpecButton.SearchProperties[WinCheckBox.PropertyNames.Name] = "Point name specific";

Mouse.Click(PointSpecButton);
Thread.Sleep(2000);

WinEdit TextInput = new WinEdit(PointBuildWin);

TextInput.SearchProperties[WinEdit.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.378734a";         

Thread.Sleep(2000);

Mouse.Click(TextInput);
TextInput.SetFocus();

Keyboard.SendKeys(TextInput, "Test");
```

Comment: "it is not working" is not a useful statement. What is it meant to be doing and what is it doing wrong? At which line in the code is the error happening? Please read [mcve] and then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try** 
TextInput.DrawHighlight() before Mouse.Click(TextInput) and confirm the search properties are pointing to right control.